# Prove or disprove this inequality involving fractions

Tags: inequality, fractions

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Assuming $x_1, x_2, x_3,...,x_{2n}$ are all positive real numbers, we need to prove or disprove:
$$\frac{x_1}{x_2}+\frac{x_2}{x_3}+...+\frac{x_{2n}}{x_1} \geq n+\frac{x_1+x_{n+1}}{x_2+x_{n+2}}+\frac{x_2+x_{n+2}}{x_3+x_{n+3}}+...+\frac{x_n+x_{2n}}{x_1+x_{n+1}}$$
Another question: if this inequality fails for general situations, for which $n$ does this inequality hold?

Any help is heartily appreciated.

Comment: from where does this inequality come?

Comment: From an old post in 2008.